# implementing copy and paste in context menu of a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, contextmenu

I have a `ListView` that shows files and folders of a computer. I have added a context menu that, when right clicked, it can copy/paste/delete/rename etc. 
When the file is selected its path is saved in a string.

Now how can I cut that and save to clipboard.
and then going to a directory and paste the file there. Copy and move to methods don't seem to work as I have to implement the copy and paste on separate clicks

```
 private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string ItemClicked = listView1.FocusedItem.Tag.ToString();
     if (ItemClicked != string.Empty)
     {
         Clipboard.SetFileDropList(ItemClicked);//error
     }
}
```

Comment: You want the text to be *cut*? As in copied to the clipboard and removed from the `listview`?

Comment: no i want the file to b cut and when i go to another dir i want to paste that file

Comment: the whole path of the file is in the ItemClicked string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in a `StringCollection` not a `string`. Try this:

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        sc.Add(listView1.FocusedItem.Tag.ToString());

        Clipboard.SetFileDropList(sc);
    }
}
```

Note though, this will only COPY to the clipboard. Inorder to cut like you want you'll need to decide what that means: delete from the `listview` or delete the file from its original location (after pasting?)

---

In response to the comments:

```
//public variables
StringCollection copiedFiles = new StringCollection();
bool cutWasSelected;

private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CopySelectedFiles();
    cutWasSelected = false;
}

private void cutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CopySelectedFiles();
    cutWasSelected = true;
}
private void CopySelectedFiles()
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            copiedFiles.Add(item.Tag.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string destinationFolder;//however you select this
    PasteCopiedFiles(destinationFolder, cutWasSelected);

}

private void PasteCopiedFiles(string DestinationFolder, bool deleteSourceFiles)
{
    if (copiedFiles.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string file in copiedFiles)
        {
            if (deleteSourceFiles)
            {
                File.Move(file,Path.Combine(new string[]{DestinationFolder,Path.GetFileName(file)}));
            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(new string[] { DestinationFolder, Path.GetFileName(file) }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ctrl+v? I thought the intention was to give the user control of the pasting function. If you are wanting to move the file solely from code the `Clipboard` is probably not the way to go. Look into the static `File` class's methods.

Comment: If that's how you want to do it I think you can do it without using the clipboard at all. Since you don't want the user to move the file outside your application/paste it using Windows Explorer, don't let them. See my update